# How to pass an array from a form into a URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, url

I have a form which uses a get method. There is a select element in the form that allows the user to select multiple options. This gets passed to the URL when the user clicks submit. However, it does not get neatly presented in the URL at all. Is there a a way to pass the array in a neat way to the URL?
(I'm using .pug because I'm using express.)

```
form(action='/FormHandler' method='get')
label(for='tags') TAGS
select(name='tags[]' multiple='')
    option(value="tag1") tag1
    option(value="tag2") tag2
    option(value="tag3") tag3
input(type='submit' value='submit')
```

I then want to take apart the URL using the `url.parse(request.url, true).query;` method in express in NodeJS.

Comment: "However, it does not get neatly presented in the URL at all. Is there a a way to pass the array in a neat way to the URL?" I assume you mean it contains `?tags[]=tag1&tags[]=tag3` - what are you looking for as a "neat way"?

Comment: Here is the URL I got when I ran my code and selected the 1st and 3rd options: http://localhost:8080/FormHandler?tags%5B%5D=%7B"name"%3A"tag1"%7D&tags%5B%5D=%7B"name"%3A"tag3"%7D

Comment: What I mean by "a neat way" is the way I concluded the question, meaning that I can take apart the URL using NodeJS's url.parse(request.url, true).query; method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`request.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) property of express gives you the desired array representation in Javascript. If tags 1 and 2 are selected, the resulting request

```
http://server/formHandler?tags[]=tag1&tags[]=tag2
```

leads to

```js
request.query = {"tags":["tag1","tag2"]}
```

There is then probably no need to parse the URL yourself using `url.parse`.

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason that is not what I got in the URL. I got this when selecting tags 1 and 3: `http://localhost:8080/FormHandler?tags%5B%5D=%7B%22name%22%3A%22tag1%22%7D&tags%5B%5D=%7B%22name%22%3A%22tag3%22%7D`

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of the form that your browser receives?

Comment: `<form action="/FormHandler" method="get">
  <label for="tags">TAGS</label>
  <select name="tags[]" multiple>
    <option value="tag1">tag1</option>
    <option value="tag2">tag2</option>
    <option value="tag3">tag3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>`

Comment: There must be an event handler that interferes with the form submission. I get the URL that I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I made I mistake when copying over the code. I changed the form and not it sends to the URL correctly.